# PYTHON INDICE Y LISTA

Tags: python, lista

tengo esto:
dpto = [11, 'a', 'b', 22, [9, 'x', 'xx', 9.9], [8, 'y', 'yy', 8.8], [7, 'z', 'zz', 7.7]]

busca(dpto, 7):
El tema est'a en que necesito saber si 7 est'a dentro de la sublista. dpto puede tener 0 o muchas cuaternas.
Logro ubicarme en el 9 pero no logro darme cuenta como pasar al elemento[0] del siguiente que seria 8, 7 etc.

```
dpto = [11, 'a', 'b', 22, [9, 'x', 'xx', 9.9], [8, 'y', 'yy', 8.8], [7, 'z', 'zz', 7.7]]
print (dpto)

def busca(lista, nro):
    for x in range(len(lista)):
        print('IMPRIME: ', lista[4][0])

print (busca(dpto, 1))
```

Comment: `return nro in lista or any(nro in sublista for sublista in lista if isinstance(sublista, list))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El primer temas es identificar de todos los elementos de `dpto` cual de ellos es una lista, para esto puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
dpto = [11, 'a', 'b', 22, [9, 'x', 'xx', 9.9], [8, 'y', 'yy', 8.8], [7, 'z', 'zz', 7.7]]

for elemento in dpto:
  if isinstance(elemento, list):
    print(elemento[0])
```

Con `for elemento in dpto` recorremos la lista y con `isinstance(elemento, list)` verificamos si a su vez el elemento es una lista. Si quieres saber si un valor se encuentra en la primer posición de alguna de las sublistas puedes hacer algo así:

```
def buscar(lista, valor):

  for elemento in lista:
    if isinstance(elemento, list):
      if valor == elemento[0]:
        return True

  return False
```

Comment: Me encanto.  No solo porque tu respuesta esta ok, sino que adem'as me olvide del isinst!...Cuidate. Saludos.